# Cant make jenkins run on https?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run jenkins on https. I have done the following:

Ran the following command to generate a private key and a certificate signing request (CSR):

```
 openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
```

I then generate a self-signed certificate by running the following command:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in yourdomain.csr -signkey yourdomain.key -out 
yourdomain.crt
```

I then modify the jenkins.xml file and add the following to the "arguments" section.

```
 --httpsPort=<port> --httpsCertificatePath=<path to crt file> --httpsPrivateKeyPath= 
  <path to key file>
```

But when i restart the service , it doesnt start. When i look at the error file , it says

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized option:
--httpsCertificatePath=C:\Program Files\Jenkins<domain_name>.crt

Any ideas on why this may be happening ?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to edit the `jenkins.xml` or add a `httpsCertificatePath` argument. Try following [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-enable-https).

Comment: yes you need to modify the file. I run on windows whereas that article is for linux and it mentions you need to modify the config / startup file in point 2.3

Comment: I have done all this , but cant browse using https, It says site cant be reached, I have opened the port in Azure aswell